# How to pick certain position from a file name in java

Tags: java

I have bellow class, the files in folder are like (xyz_1_071_basefiles_**03272**_30087.txt.)

and the position that I have bold I want to pick it that part only and sort it, and from that if the value is not addition like bellow example

it's okay to be like this

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
```

but if it's like bellow

```
10000
10001
10003
10004
```

then I want to show those two file digits 10001, 10003 as between these two 10002 is missing , bellow is the code I have done so far.

```
public loopMe() {

         File dir = new File(path);
         File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
         if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                //System.out.println(child.getName());
                String filename = child.getName();
                String filename1 = filename.substring(24,30);
                System.out.println(filename1);
            }
          } else {

          }

    }
```

Comment: You want to show 10002 as missing between 10001 & 10003?

Comment: yes right, and also the sub string that I used is not picking that part, as the position of digits are not fixed it keep grow and shrink... but position of _ are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to include way to get digits from filename:

```
Integer sequenceNo = Integer.parseInt(filename.split("_")[4]);
```

This will split the filename on the `_` character, then you retrieve the 4th element.

Building on your existing code, convert the part of the filename you've extracted into an Integer (as shown above), put them all into a List and sort it, a bit like this:

```
List<Integer> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
for (File child : directoryListing) {
    String filename = child.getName();
    String filename1 = filename.substring(24,30);
    filenames.add(Integer.parseInt(filename1));
}
Collections.sort(filenames);
```

Now loop over the list looking to see if the current entry - 1 > 1 difference, something like this (untested):

```
int previousInSequence = filenames.get(0);
for (Integer currentSequence : filenames) {
    if (currentSequence - previousInSequence > 1) {
        // you have missing files
        // currentSequence - previousInSequence will tell you how many

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help But I cannot make this part work to grab xyz_1_071_basefiles_03272_30087.txt. the int part as the digit is not fixed it keep grow and shrink but the position of _ are fixed... with substring that I use it cannot pick that part

Comment: Hi thanks for replay... i'm getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: The code I provided has no error checking built-in, you'll have to provide that yourself.  The error is telling you you have an array with no elements in but you're trying to access element at index 0.

Comment: Hi thanks for replay I figure that part out...how can I print the file name also since it won't tell me between which files there is missing...

Comment: You have absolutely no way to know the name of the file unless you can work it out from the sequence number

Comment: Also - if this answer has helped you with your original question, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Okay thanks I will do that but one quick question when I run it I will be getting output something like this 2
6
7
8
9 am I doing something wrong or that is expected

Comment: If those are missing from your sequence then yes, that sounds right to me.  Only you know your requirements